# Simple-Ajax-Uploader PHP code doesnt return any response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use the Simple-Ajax-Uploader but it gives me the following output:

```
GET <URL> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong
My php code:

```
<?php 
require('Uploader.php'); 

 // Directory where we're storing uploaded images 
 // Remember to set correct permissions or it won't work 
 $upload_dir = '/uploads/'; 

 echo "reached";
 $uploader = new FileUpload('uploadfile'); 

 // Handle the upload 
 $result = $uploader->handleUpload($upload_dir); 

 if (!$result) {
    exit (json_encode(array('success' => false, 'msg' => $uploader->getErrorMsg())));   
} 

   echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'file' => $uploader->getFileName()));

?>
```

Uploader.php can be found : https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader/blob/master/extras/Uploader.php

Comment: Open your developer's console and see what' going on there.

Comment: I dont see anything going on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the webserver that i was using, It was unable to invoke/execute php script.